# I need to change the date format from 14 April,2015 to YYYY-mm-DD in php

Tags: php, date

I need to change the date format from 14 April,2015 to YYYY-MM-DD in php.
I tried the following code

```
$your_date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($date));
```

The output is 1970-01-01. please let me know the steps to proceed

Comment: `print date('Y-m-d',strtotime(str_replace(',',' ','14 April,2015')));`

Comment: The `,` break the `strtotime` function

Comment: I checked that link but doesnt work Could you anyone help

Comment: `$your_date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime(str_replace(",", " ", $date));` this will work. Now it's not working because you have comma in string. The other way is to use DateTime::createFromFormat and give your own format with comma

Comment: Hi JustOnUnderMillions  the above code doesnt work

Comment: Hi Robert could you please help with datetime:createfrom format.

Comment: I have kept my field as Date (ISO format)